# What is install process of software like phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, webserver

I access my website on server like this

```
85.25.149.143/my-site-name
```

This is because my-site-name folder exist in directory `/usr/www/html/`.

I can also access the phpmyadmin application the same way:

```
85.25.149.143/phpmyadmin
```

Even though the `phpmyadmin` folder does not exist in directory `/usr/www/html/`. Why does this work?

What configuration allows the phpmyadmin application to be accessed it through a web browser, even though it's not in the public HTML folder?

Comment: FYI: I tried to clarify your question. If my interpretation was wrong, feel free to roll it back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your webserver software and how that's configured. In many Linux distributions, there's a folder where additional webserver configuration files are kept to be automatically loaded by the web server. In Debian (and probably Debian-like distributions) with Apache, it's somewhere in `/etc/apache2/`, in the case of phpMyAdmin and Debian they put it at `/etc/apache2/conf.d/`. It seems you're not using Debian (due to your webserver root being `/usr/www/html`), so exact paths may differ but the concept is the same. When the package manager installs phpMyAdmin or any other web program, it puts configuration files there which Apache reads automatically to access the files installed in another location (which is generally `/usr/share/...` to keep with policy). Anyway, putting the files there is an automatic way to accomplish the same thing you can do by manually editing the Apache configuration file, which is basically using an Alias to tell Apache to look somewhere else. Other webservers have similar means as well.

[Aliases](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) look like `Alias /foo /usr/local/bar` -- which means by accessing http://example.com/foo you get the folder of `/usr/local/bar`. It's great for distributions which have policies of not putting end-user files in `/var/www` for instance.

tl;dr - an Apache alias exists (probably in a file named something similar to `phpmyadmin.conf` in a subfolder of `/etc/apache2/`, although details vary by distribution), which tells your webserver to load the phpMyAdmin folder (which may be under `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` folder) and present it as if it were in `/usr/www/html`.